# ITextSharp errror "Off is not a valid name for a checkbox appearance (should be Off or Yes)"

Tags: itext

Running the following code snippet under VS 2010 using iTextSharp 5.5.6:

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Test.pdf");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("New.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        PdfStamper p = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);
        AcroFields form = p.AcroFields;

        ...

        RadioCheckField newField = new RadioCheckField(p.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(20, 20), "MyCheckBox", "Off");

        PdfFormField RadioField = newField.CheckField;

        p.AddAnnotation(RadioField, 1);
```

I receive the error "ITextSharp errror "Off is not a valid name for a checkbox appearance (should be Off or Yes)" at the line declaring the RadioField object. Is this a bug? How do I work around it?

Comment: I was confused by the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A check box can have two values:

- one you define yourself in your method. That will be the value of the check box when selected.
- one that is defined in ISO-32000-1: `Off`. That's the value of the check box when it's not selected.

There is a bug in *your* code because you are trying to create a check box of which the value is *always* `Off` whether it's selected or not.

Choose another value. `Off` is reserved for the *off state*. You need yo define a value for the *on state*. ISO-32000-1 recommends `Yes`.

This is how you make sure the check box is selected:

```
newField.Checked = true;
```

Unchecked is done like this:

```
newField.Checked = false;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was confused by the phrasing of the error message. I was trying to set the default value of the check box (e.g, "Off" vs. "Yes") using this method, not specify the value for the on state. That is, I wasn't using the right method for setting that default value. What I ended up doing was using the value "Yes", and then calling

form.SetField("MyCheckBox", "Yes");